# How to use variable after as in statement of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Origin table

| So | So_Line | So other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 | rrr35 |
| BDC | 2 | rrr35 |

Result table

| So | So_Line | So other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-1 | 2 | rrr35 |
| ABC-2 | 2 | rrr35 |
| ABC-3 | 2 | rrr35 |
| ABC-4 | 2 | rrr35 |
| ABC-5 | 2 | rrr35 |
| BDC-1 | 2 | rrr35 |
| BDC-2 | 2 | rrr35 |

It didn't work this way

```
DECLARE @MyVariable VARCHAR(max);
SET @MyVariable = 'So,So_Line,So_other';

SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) AS @MyVariable
FROM [test].[dbo].[foo] 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('-1'),('-2'),('-3'),('-4'),('-5')) t(x) 
WHERE So = 'ABC'

UNION

SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) AS @MyVariable
FROM [test].[dbo].[foo] 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('-1'),('-2')) t(x) 
WHERE So = 'BDC'
```

But it did work this way:

```
SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) AS So, So_Line, So_other
FROM [test].[dbo].[foo] 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('-1'),('-2'),('-3'),('-4'),('-5')) t(x) 
WHERE So = 'ABC'

UNION 

SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) AS So, So_Line, So_other 
FROM [test].[dbo].[foo] 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('-1'),('-2')) t(x) 
WHERE So = 'BDC'
```

The table is just example, the table what I deal with have like 300 columns and I can't just add after the as, so I think I can create a variable.

But it didn't work near `@MyVariable`, could anyone help me?

Comment: Your `SELECT` query will return multiple rows, but you can only use a single-column in a single-row query to assign to a T-SQL variable (`SET @myVariable = (SELECT TOP 1 x FROM y ORDER BY z)` or `SELECT @myVariable = x FROM y ORDER BY z OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`). That `CONCAT` function is not an aggregate function like `STRING_AGG`. Also, what is the purpose of that `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: In this case  i wanna dublicated rows and it dublicated 5 rows , the reason i wanna use variable is the table i deal with have so much columns, so i need use a variable to keep the statement concise.

Comment: _"the reason i wanna use variable is the table i deal with have so much columns, so i need use a variable to keep the statement concise."_ - Please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: Do you want to *set* the value of that variable through that SELECT statement, or do you want to specify columns to select? You can only use variables for values, not for parts of the syntax (like name of table or columns). Unless you use dynamic sql and build a query in a string

Comment: I re-edit the quetion, sry about the confuse

Comment: Expected results would help as well.

Comment: It *seems* that you don't need any of this dynamic query at all. You just need `SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) AS SO, So_Line, So_Other FROM...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Variable is a value holder so it SQL Server treats it accordingly.

To achieve the desired result you should go for dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @MyVariable VARCHAR(max);
SET @MyVariable = 'So,So_Line,So_other';
DECLARE @Dynamic_Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Dynamic_Query=' SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x) as ['+@MyVariable+']
FROM   [test].[dbo].[foo] CROSS JOIN (VALUES(''-1''),(''-2''),(''-3''),(''-4''),(''-5'')) t(x) WHERE  So = ''ABC''
Union
SELECT CONCAT(So, t.x)
FROM   [test].[dbo].[foo] CROSS JOIN (VALUES(''-1''),(''-2'')) t(x) WHERE  So = ''BDC'''

exec(@Dynamic_Query)
```

Thanks!

Comment: sry, actually it didn't work it's only one column [So,So_Line,So_other], i expect 3 colums. Like [So.],[So_Line],[So_other]

Comment: I figure it out.  it should like this ..... as '+@MyVariable+'From......  No square brackets. But thanks anyway!